# Getting error while use of ckeditor only in chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, textarea

[image: Getting]

getting above type of error in chrome browser only while integrate ckeditor its working fine for Firefox.

I calling below function for all text area of my project.

```
function getCKeditorSource($field_id, $field_name, $field_value = "")     {
 ?>
<textarea id="<?php echo $field_id ?>" name="<?php echo $field_name ? >"><?php echo stripslashes($field_value); ?></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){

        CKEDITOR.replace( '<?php echo $field_name ?>',{
            filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
            filebrowserUploadUrl : 'ckeditor/ckeditor/uploader/upload.php',
            toolbar : 'MyToolbar',
            width: "100%"
        });
    });
</script>   

<?php
  }
```

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: Can you please add text of those error ?

Comment: @soyab : Without code how to solve ?

Comment: First check your version because sometimes some versions are working on chrome

Comment: Please Post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a issue this type of error generate due to catch of browser. this type of issue found just clear your catch first.

Thanks all who take interest here.

Answer (score 2):

I have created one demo. It's working, please check this.

```
<textarea cols="80" id="ckeditor" name="ckeditor" rows="10">Ckeditor</textarea>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
</script>
```

Comment: May be problem with my version you are correct @Neel Thakkar